# Google chart API styling tooltips

Tags: charts, tooltip, google-visualization

Is there a way to style Tooltips in Google chart API? I've managed to only change the color of text using [`tooltip.textStyle`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#Configuration_Options). So is there any solution to change the **white background** to some **other color** (as shown on picture):

[image]

Test playground http://jsfiddle.net/nyNAg/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution through serendipity:

```
<style>
path {
  fill: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Anyway, I did not find any configuration option for background in the google charts API.

Comment: I've edited the selector to match only the tooltip bubble http://jsfiddle.net/nyNAg/21/

Comment: Is it possible to change the tooltip's background right at `var options = { }`? For example, to make a chart transparent, you can set `var options = {backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent'} };`

Comment: I used `.google-visualization-tooltip path {
       fill: yellow;
    }`

Answer (score 5):

Enable the tooltip to be handled by the HTML by writing this code in your options of google charts
CODE: `tooltip: { isHtml: true }` (,) add a comma if needed. :)

Now you can style tooltip using HTML and css. :)

/*CSS Styling*/

To style the tooltip box :

```
div.google-visualization-tooltip {}
```

To style the content like font size, color, etc

```
div.google-visualization-tooltip > ul > li > span {}
```

Use `!important` whenever needed ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/nyNAg/66/

Comment: where would one put/append custom strings

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to completely replace the label with custom HTML. It's maybe a bit complicated, but gives you full control of the content and style. See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#custom_html_content

Answer (score 0):

As the Google Chart Tools API implements its SVG charts via an iframe hosted on it's servers, as per the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you may not access or modify the content of another domain, unless via server-side manipulation prior to sending the client a response.

Given that, I'm not sure how you managed to change the text colour - perhaps a browser bug?

Comment: There's a configuration option for text color "tooltip.textStyle" but not for background color. I've edited the SVG using Firebug only to show what am I trying to achieve (and made a screenshot).

Comment: I see your link. Other than those style's Google have specifically offered via the API I can't see how there would be any way round this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to override inline-style rules e.g.

li.google-visualization-tooltip-item span[style] { font-weight: normal !important; }

http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/